# YouTube keeps showing same videos on the home screen

Tags: youtube

YouTube keeps showing same videos on the home screen. I have enabled the search and watch history. How can this be diversified?

Answer (score -1):

Try turning on **Ad Personalisation** in your Google Account settings.